# Show that the equation of a trajectory is a parabola with a given equation

Tags: classical-mechanics, kinematics

A projectile is launched from the origin (so close to the Earth that it can be modelled with $a(t)=-g $ with speed $v_0$ at an angle $\theta$ to the (positive) horizontal.

I'm trying to show that, if $R=$range of the projectile, then the Cartesian equation of the trajectory is given by: $y=\frac{4h}{R^2}x(R-x)$.

Here's my working:
[image]

As you can see, I'm stuck on the last line and have no idea how to progress, without going in circles.

Could someone tell me whether or I'm going wrong and how to get out of this mess?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first expression in the first line after "Substituting this into $(2)$ yields" should be:
$$y=x \frac{\sin \theta}{\cos \theta} - \frac{1}{2} g  \frac{x^2}{ v_0^2 \cos ^2 \theta} \Rightarrow $$
$$y=x \tan \theta - \frac{1}{2} g  \frac{x^2}{ v_0^2 \cos ^2 \theta} \quad(1)$$

Note that two of your expressions (for $h$ and $R$) can be changed to:
$$ \tan \theta = \frac{4h}{R} \quad(2)$$
and
$$\frac{g}{2v_0^2 \cos ^2 \theta}= \frac{\tan \theta}{R}. \quad(3)$$

Now substitute $(2)$ and $(3)$ in $(1)$ and you will get the desired expression.

Comment: Thanks. I've corrected my mistake (on my original, not on MSE), but I still don't know how to tidy it up. Could you give me a hint?